# Comma in chemical formula

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

I am using the `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` package, and would like to write the formula for Dolomite in my report: (Ca,Mg)CO3

So far I haven't found a way to get that comma right in my formula using the `mhchem` package, and haven't found anyone having had troubles doing that so far. Anyone could help me doing so?

Cheers!

Comment: Dolomite is CaMg(CO3)2. What you write, (Ca,Mg)CO3 is Mg-rich calcite that is a different mineral to dolomite and has different crystal structure and properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP's formula (Ca,Mg)CO3 is completely fine and meets IUPAC recommendations [[1, p. 21](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf#page=33)], section IR-2.2.3.1:

> (d) In solid-state chemistry, to enclose symbols of atoms occupying the same type of site in a random fashion. The symbols themselves are separated by a comma, with no space.
>
> *Example:*
>
> 9. K(Br,Cl)

To achieve this with `mhchem`, the sane way would be to use braces around the comma (as mentioned in the comments): `{,}`. Note that `chemformula` doesn't require the comma to be escaped and renders the formula correctly "as is":

[image: (Ca,Mg)CO3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        modules = all
    }

\begin{document}

\ce{(Ca{,}Mg)CO3} (\texttt{mhchem})

\ch{(Ca,Mg)CO3} (\texttt{chemformula})

\end{document}
```

#### References

1. IUPAC “Red Book” Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; *IUPAC Recommendations; Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, UK*, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2. [PDF](https://old.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf)